# Limit of a integral with arctan function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

Let the sequence $I_n$ , $n\ge 2$ and $$I_n=\int^n_0 x^n\arctan(x^\frac{1}{n})\,dx$$.
Calculate:
$\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{I_n}{n^n}$
I tried to divide the integral in two different ones , or to apply the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals but I didn't get to any point.

Comment: The nice property a out $\arctan$ is its derivative. Use IBP.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't know what it is IBP. Could you tell me what it is?

Comment: Am anothet thin that you tell me to do to solve this problem is to derivate arctan ,right?

Comment: IBP=integrate by parts

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $t = \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n+1}$

$$ \frac{I_n}{n^n} = \frac{n}{n+1}\int_0^1 \arctan\left(n^{\frac{1}{n}}t^{\frac{1}{n^2+n}}\right)\:dt \to \int_0^1 \arctan(1)\:dt = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Could you detail the calcul through which you got to that result, because I did the substitution that you sugessted and I did not get to the rase result.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $x=y^n.$ The integral becomes

$$\int_0^{n^{1/n}} y^{n^2}(\arctan y) ny^{n-1}\,dy$$ $$ \le (\arctan n^{1/n})n\int_0^{n^{1/n}} y^{n^2+n-1}\,dy.$$

For an estimate from below, integrate over $[1,n^{1/n}].$